# Dart runtimeType checking in switch statement

Tags: types, switch-statement, dart

I have found some strange behaviors trying to check the runtime type of some objects in Dart.
Let's make a simple example:

```
main(List<String> args) {
  List<Map> l1 = new List<Map>();
  l1.add(new Map<String, int>());
  List<int> l2 = ['Start', 'Stop'];
  checkType(l1.runtimeType);
  checkType(l1[0].runtimeType);
  checkType(l2.runtimeType);
}

checkType(Type type) {

  switch(type) {
    case List:
      print('it is a List!');
      break;
    case Map:
      print('it is a List!');
      break;
    default:
      print('Unmanaged type $type');
      break;
  }
}
```

this program has the following output:

Unmanaged type `List<Map>` 
Unmanaged type `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, int>`
Unmanaged type `List`

The first case cannot be checked in a switch statement because if I try to set a "`List<Map>`" case I get the error: in constant expressions, operand(s) of this operator must be of type 'num'
The second cannot be matched because using the _InternalLinkedHashMap in a case gets the following error: Case expression must be constant.

In the last case I have defined the List as a List of ints (`List<int>`), but the system ignores it and considers it as a simple List.
I think that this is misleading and such a declaration should be forbbiden.

Any help/suggestion?

Comment: I think you would get a lot of help from Strong mode in this. It'd give you a few more warnings/errors.

Comment: Use `is` for type checks, e.g. `if (type is List) {...} else if (type is Map) {...} else {...}`. A `switch` statement won't work here, and generic parameters will not be checked

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do flow control based on object's type, you actually want to do it based on whether an object's class implements an *interface*, not what it's run time type is. This is what the **Type Test Operators** `is` and `is!` are for.

Remember that in Dart a class is also an interface, so you can test if an object is a specific class.

```
class Something {
 ...
}

var s = new Something();
print(s is Something);     // true
```

Note that things we tend to think of as 'classes' such as `List` an `Map`, are not classes, they are interfaces. Anything that returns a instance of such (including constructors) in fact returns a class that implements the interface.

You can use generics, but be careful.

```
void main() {

  var a = [1, 2, 'three'];
  print(a is List);          // True
  print(a is List<int>);     // True!!!!
  print(a is List<String>);  // True!!!!

  var b = new List<int>.from([1, 2, 3]);
  print(b is List);          // True
  print(b is List<int>);     // True
  print(b is List<String>);  // False
}
```

A class can implement an interface via explicitly implementing it, inheriting from a class that implements it, or through a mix-in.

```
class Base {
  void a() {}
}

class Mix {
  void b() {}
}

class Mixed extends Base with Mix {} 

class Explicit implements Base {
  void a() {}  
}

void main() {

  var c = new Mixed();
  print(c is Mixed);         // True
  print(c is Base);          // True
  print(c is Mix);           // True

  var d = new Explicit();
  print(d is Base);          // True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to get runtimetype from the object

```
switch(type.runtimeType)
```

Check this answer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/71529798/8192246