# Dart see if Instance of type inherits from other type

Tags: dart

```
class a {/*code*/}
class b extends a {/*more code*/}
void main() {
  b c = new b();
  print(c.runtimeType == a); //type == inheritedType
  //or
  print(c.runtimeType inherits a); //operator for inheritance
  //or
  print(c inherits a); //other operator for inheritance
}
```

Can you use `type == inheriting type`, `type inherits other type`, or `instance inherits other type or type`?
Is there even a way to do such thing?
Because I have not found any way yet.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354210/dart-runtimetype-checking-in-switch-statement/38360629

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `is`.

You can do `c is a`. Notice that `new a() is a` is `true` as well. If you really want to know if an instance is a subtype of another type, you might ask `c is a && c.runtimeType != a`.

Comment: they need a better search engine on the API docs because I cannot find this anywhere :P

Comment: Dart Language tour is best place to look for language details: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators

Comment: I just picked up dart and found stuff out as i went along as i had lots of experience in java and javascript