# Convert data Type into different data Type in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working in backend using dart. when i get a request i check the data type of all the values in key value pair. some times i receive data type.

`_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`

I need a where i can type cast a data-type

```
Type xyz = sumFunction(_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>);
print(xyz);

output : 
Map<String,dynamic>
```

Beacause when i am comparing

```
print(_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> == Map<String,dynamic>);

output:
false
```

If anyone have any kind of solution please provide.

Comment: in Dart you can check if a class inherits other this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/41127972/3743245 but it should be enough if you assume that every response you get, is a Map

Comment: [`is` is for checking if an object *instance* is of a specified `Type`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61553561/).  You cannot use it to compare `Type`s.  You could use `==`, but that's generally not advised since it checks an identical `Type` and will not check if one `Type` derives from the other.  In general, comparing `Type`s is a bad idea.  What is the problem you're ultimately trying to solve?