# DART: type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the day of a Firestore TimeStamp type field.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph4tY.png)

This is the field in firestore:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAGwt.png)

I have try some cast but anything works.

This is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vm2V.png)

If i remove the .toString() i get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8bKf.png)

I want just the day of the date:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0UR9.png)

Comment: You need to convert the data type.  DATE types are very specific, and even if the string matches the date format, unless its converted to that type, it still considers it a string.  Here is a link on how to do that ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229222/convert-data-type-into-different-data-type-in-dart

Comment: You are welcome, good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this :

```
Text(DateFormat('dd').format(
DateTime.parse(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['dia'].toDate()),).toString())
```