# The switch case expression type 'Type' must be a subtype of the switch expression type 'BankEvent'

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

I am getting this error when I try to use switch case in dart. I have an abstract class and two classes extending it. See the code below

```
abstract class BankEvent{}

class FetchBanks extends BankEvent{}

class DeleteBank extends BankEvent{
  final int bankId;
  DeleteBank(this.bankId);
}
```

I have to make some implementations inside the handleEvents method depends on the instance of the class I am receiving as parameter. But I am getting the error (The switch case expression type 'Type' must be a subtype of the switch expression type 'BankEvent') in the case statement of switch case. My code for the switch case implementation is below

```
handleEvents(BankEvent bankEvent){
    switch(bankEvent){
      case FetchBanks:
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure.  At first pass, `FetchBanks` is of type `Class`, which might be causing the error.  Try modify the switch in either respect and see if it removes the error.

Comment: I am not getting your point

Comment: For example, in the switch statement, replace `switch(bankevent)` with `switch(bankevent.getClass())`.

Comment: If you're looking for something similar to sealed classes in Kotlin or enums in Swift, you may be interested in the freezed package: https://pub.dev/packages/freezed. Otherwise, the if-else approach is the way to go

Comment: If else approach is working fine. But if there are many events then switch is the better way right. I will look in to freezed package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah finally I found the answer after a bit of research.It should be writtern as below

```
handleEvents(BankEvent bankEvent){
    switch(bankEvent.runtimeType){
      case FetchBanks:
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change your swith to an if statement, like so:

```
handleEvents(BankEvent bankEvent){ 
   if(bankEvent is FetchBank){
      // FetchBank stuff
   }else if(bankEvent is DeleteBank){
      // DeleteBank stuff
   }
}
```

This works and is quite readable. Besides, you can get rid off the switch approach.

Comment: That's javascript type checking - The dart way to check the type is `if (bankEvent is FetchBank) {...}`

Comment: @MichaelHorn https://stackoverflow.com/a/71529798/8192246

Comment: Thanks for the info, the question had the java tag which disoriented me